# Core animation returns layer to the original position when label's text is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I've got simple animation which moves my view's layer and remains in it's final state.

```
CGPoint originalPosition = self.redSquare.layer.position;
self.redSquare.layer.position   = CGPointMake(100, 100);
CABasicAnimation *animation = [[CABasicAnimation alloc]init];
animation.keyPath = @"position.x";
animation.fromValue = @(originalPosition.x);
animation.toValue = @250;
animation.duration = 2;

[self.redSquare.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"basic"];
self.redSquare.layer.position = CGPointMake(250, originalPosition.y);
```

But when I change a label's text the layer jumps to it's original position.

```
CGPoint originalPosition = self.redSquare.layer.position;
self.redSquare.layer.position   = CGPointMake(100, 100);
CABasicAnimation *animation = [[CABasicAnimation alloc]init];
animation.keyPath = @"position.x";
animation.fromValue = @(originalPosition.x);
animation.toValue = @250;
animation.duration = 2;
animation.delegate = self;

[self.redSquare.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"basic"];
self.redSquare.layer.position = CGPointMake(250, originalPosition.y);

self.label.text = @"Started";
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because,when you change your text,the view need to redraw,

If you enable autoLayout of this view(default is enabled), it will adjust frame to autolayout.

So there are to solutions

**Option 1:**
Disable auto layout of your view

**Option 2**
When it comes to frame changed animation, try to animate autolayout